# dmultinom discrepancy

Tags: r, distributions, capture-mark-recapture

I am trying to write a simple Maximum Likelihood Estimator based on the following pmf for the multinomial distribution.

$$f(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{k};n,p_{1},\ldots ,p_{k})=\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!} p_1^{x_1} \cdots p_k^{x_k}$$

My specific experiment has four possible outcomes with the following distribution:

$$P(n_{1},n_{2},m_{2}|N,p_{1},p_{2})=\frac{N!}{m_2!(n_{1}-m_{2})!(n_{2}-m_{2})!(N-r)!} (p_{1}p_{2})^{m_2}(p_{1}q_{2})^{n_{1}-m_{2}}(q_{1}p_{2})^{n_{2}-m_{2}}(q_{1}q_{2})^{N-r}$$

Where $q_{i}=1-p_{i}$ and $r=n_{1}+n_{2}-m_{2}$

This is a Lincoln-Petersen estimator.

I write this out in R, and for completeness, also include a version using the gamma function, and Rs internal **dmultinom**.

```
n_1<-10
n_2<-10
m_2<-2
N<-52
r<-n_1+n_2-m_2
p_1<-0.2
p_2<-0.2
q_1<-1-p_1
q_2<-1-p_2

(factorial(N)/(factorial(m_2)*factorial(n_1-m_2)*factorial(n_2-m_2)*factorial(N-r)))*(((p_1*p_2)^m_2)*((p_1*q_2)^(n_1-m_2))*((q_1*p_2)^(n_2-m_2))*((q_1*q_2)^(N-r)))
#[1] 0.006376341
(gamma(sum(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r))+1)/prod(gamma(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r)+1)))*(((p_1*p_2)^m_2)*((p_1*q_2)^(n_1-m_2))*((q_1*p_2)^(n_2-m_2))*((q_1*q_2)^(N-r)))
#[1] 0.006376341
dmultinom(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r),prob=c(p_1*p_2,p_1*q_2,q_1*p_2,q_1*q_2))
#[1] 0.006376341
```

My issue is that none of these are returning the same value when I understand them to be calculating the same thing. Additionally the first equation is the only one that is providing ML estimates within the range that I expect. Have I missed an obvious bracket somewhere or am I just completely off?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: In the denominator of your second expression you seem to equate the Gamma function with the factorial, but they are not the same: $x! = \Gamma(x+1).$

Comment: @AdamO I've edited to include the missing information. Though I can't seem to reproduce the original example I had.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for spotting a missing +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely just a computational issue. Evaluating a likelihood that has factorial terms w/o log transform is begging for precision errors. Do a log instead. `lgamma(x+1)` is MUCH more stable than `log(factorial(x))`. OR just use `dmultinom` and input the probability vector. `dmultinom` uses log-gamma functions anyway.

```
dmultinom(c(10, 20, 30, 40), prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
exp(lgamma(101) - lgamma(41) - lgamma(31) - lgamma(21) - lgamma(11) 
  + 10 * log(0.25) + 20 * log(0.25) + 30 * log(0.25) + 40 * log(0.25))
```

gives:

```
> dmultinom(c(10, 20, 30, 40), prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
[1] 3.039567e-08
> exp(lgamma(101) - lgamma(41) - lgamma(31) - lgamma(21) - lgamma(11) + 10 * log(0.25) + 20 * log(0.25) + 30 * log(0.25) + 40 * log(0.25))
[1] 3.039567e-08
```

Comment: I'm now getting agreement between the equation with factorial terms, and dmultinom. But the former is performing better in the MLE.